# Titanium label setVisible / hide not working

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

I have this code (Android app):
https://gist.github.com/eladmeidar/8115896

after clicking the `btnSearch` imageView, the `txtSearch` field is being displayed but the `lblTitle` doesn't hide, doesn't change text. nothing. no errors on log.